# Save tensorflow model to file

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, pickle

I create a tensorflow model which I would like to save to file so that I can predict against it later.  In particular, I need to save the:

- input_placeholder
  (`= tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, iVariableLen])`)
- solution_space
  (`= tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(input_placeholder, weight_variable) + bias_variable)`)
- session
  (`= tf.Session()`)

I've tried using pickle which works on other objects like sklearn binarizers etc, but not on the above, for which I get the error at the bottom.

How I pickle:

```
import pickle
with open(sModelSavePath, 'w') as fiModel:
    pickle.dump(dModel, fiModel)
```

where `dModel` is a dictionary that contains all the objects I want to persist, which I use for fitting against.

Any suggestions on how to pickle tensorflow objects?

**Error message**:

```
pickle.dump(dModel, fiModel)
...
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle module objects
```

Comment: Can you use Tensorflow's built-in feature for this? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I solved this was by [pickleing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) Sklearn objects like binarizers, and using [tensorflow's inbuilt save functions](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variables/index.html#saving-and-restoring) for the actual model:

**Saving tensorflow model**:
1)  Build the model as you usually would
2)  Save the session with `tf.train.Saver()`.  For example:

```
oSaver = tf.train.Saver()

oSess = oSession
oSaver.save(oSess, sModelPath)  #filename ends with .ckpt
```

3)  This saves all available variables etc in that session to their variable names.

**Loading tensorflow model**:
1)  The entire flow needs to be re-initialized. In other words, variables, weights, bias, loss function etc need to be declared, and then initialized with `tf.initialize_all_variables()` being passed into `oSession.run()`
2)  That session now needs to be passed to the loader.  I abstracted the flow, so my loader looks like this:

```
dAlg = tf_training_algorithm()  #defines variables etc and initializes session

oSaver = tf.train.Saver()
oSaver.restore(dAlg['oSess'], sModelPath)

return {
    'oSess': dAlg['oSess'],
    #the other stuff I need from my algorithm, like my solution space etc
}
```

3)  All objects you need for prediction need to be gotten out of your initialisation, which in my case sit in dAlg

PS: Pickle like this:

```
with open(sSavePathFilename, 'w') as fiModel:
    pickle.dump(dModel, fiModel)

with open(sFilename, 'r') as fiModel:
    dModel = pickle.load(fiModel)
```

Comment: appreciate this answer but what is `oSession`?

Answer (score 0):

You should save your project into two separate parts, one is for `tensorflow`'s objects, another is for other objects. I recommend you to use the following tools:

1. [tf.saved_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/serving_basic): the procedures your want to saved and load `tensorflow` all in it.
2. [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill): a more powerful pickle tool based on `pickle`, it can help you bypass most errors encountered by `pickle`