# NotFoundError while using pickle dump to save a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pickle

I have created a model named 'model' but when I'm trying to save it using pickle it just gives an 'NotFoundError'.

```
import pickle
with open("test.pkl","wb") as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
```

This is the error message I get upon running the code.

Error message

```
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: ram://471dfd58-f3fe-4d9f-9075-60a1568cc629/assets
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-0abd122520e5> in <module>
      1 import pickle
      2 with open("test.pkl","wb") as file:
----> 3     pickle.dump(model, file)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in __reduce__(self)
    313     if self.built:
    314       return (pickle_utils.deserialize_model_from_bytecode,
--> 315               pickle_utils.serialize_model_as_bytecode(self))
    316     else:
    317       # SavedModel (and hence serialize_model_as_bytecode) only support

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\pickle_utils.py in serialize_model_as_bytecode(model)
     75         with tf.io.gfile.GFile(dest_path, "rb") as f:
     76           info = tarfile.TarInfo(name=os.path.relpath(dest_path, temp_dir))
---> 77           info.size = f.size()
     78           archive.addfile(tarinfo=info, fileobj=f)
     79   tf.io.gfile.rmtree(temp_dir)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in size(self)
     97   def size(self):
     98     """Returns the size of the file."""
---> 99     return stat(self.__name).length
    100 
    101   def write(self, file_content):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in stat(filename)
    908     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    909   """
--> 910   return stat_v2(filename)
    911 
    912 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\lib\io\file_io.py in stat_v2(path)
    924     errors.OpError: If the operation fails.
    925   """
--> 926   return _pywrap_file_io.Stat(compat.path_to_str(path))
    927 
    928 

NotFoundError:
```

Any help would be massively appreciated

Comment: your error shows problem with reading file `open('model_pkl' , 'rb')` and `pickle.load(f)`, not with writing.

Comment: @furas Actually open('model_pkl','rb') was the next cell following this error message and it got copied by mistake. Error message just ends with ' NotFoundError: '. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but hopefully it still helps.

I had the same problem, and the same error. I ended up avoiding it by using Keras save and load methods instead of pickle. I don't know what your model is but you might want to try the same. It might be due to what is [pickeleable](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle). Maybe the answer given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38000180/save-tensorflow-model-to-file) helps, they argue for saving tensorflow object separately.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know I'm super late. I ended up doing the same, used keras save and saved my model as a .h5 config and it worked without any problem.